# Can a Java application or any other application other then .NET can consume WCF enabled application

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a console application in which I have exposed interface having 
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)] attribute.

If yes how can Java application call methods exposed in WCF application?

Note: its not a WCF sevice so we not having Service refence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple Service Calls you can use BasicHttpBinding.

Edit: Found a link Blog Site: [WCF & Java Interop](http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop)

For advanced there is a Project from Sun called Web Services Interoperability Technologies (WSIT)

take a look at [Project Site](https://wsit.dev.java.net/)
you can found a little introduction at [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/news/Project-Tango-WCF-Java-Interop)